# Executing two ajax calls serially

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the two ajax calls below that are made when a user clicks a button to open a gallery:

```
              // Get the sub-folders and their position 
$.post('ajax.php', {op : 'get_folders'},       
                           function() {  
                                       . . .
                           });

             // Get the gallery thumbs

$("#galleryContent").load("ajax.php", 
                           {op : 'get_thumbs' 
                           },
                           function() {  
                                . . .                 
                            });
```

It wouldn't be good to launch into the second ajax call before the first one is done so I think I need to use .when(), .done(), or .then() somehow to synchronize these calls, but no simple solution is dropping out of the deferred documentation for me. Does someone see a simple way to do this? I don't need to pass any variables from the first call to the second call. I just want to hold off the second until the first is done.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var f1 = function () {
    return $.post("ajax.php", {op : "get_folders"});
}
, f2 = function () {
    var dfd = new $.Deferred();
    $("#galleryContent")
        .load("ajax.php", {
            op : "get_thumbs"
    }, function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
        dfd.resolve(data, textStatus, jqxhr)
    });
    return dfd.promise()
}
, requests = [f1, f2]
, request = function (arr) {
    return $.when(arr[0]())
        .then(function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) { // `done` callbacks
           console.log(
             typeof data === "string" 
             ? data : data[0]
             , textStatus, jqxhr
           );
           if (arr.length !== 1) {
              arr.shift();
              request(arr)
           }
        }, function (jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { // `fail` callbacks
            console.log(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
        })
};

request(requests);
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/ruoq3kf5/

Answer (score 1):

The simplest I can think of is:

```
//make the second ajax call
$("#galleryContent").load("ajax.php",{op : 'get_thumbs' }, function() {  
    //. . .
    //once it successfully completes, make the first ajax call
    $.post('ajax.php', {op : 'get_folders'}, function() {  
         //. . .
    });             
});
```

Comment: I thought about putting the second call in the completion function of the first,  but the second call is has a lot of processing and I didn't want to bury all that code in a completion function. If there's a clean way to do with when(), etc. I'd rather do that.

Answer (score 1):

Like you said, two words: when and done.

```
$.when(ajax1()).done(function()
{
    ajax2();
});
```

and you must return the jqXHR object for any ajax request

```
function ajax1()
{
    return $.post({...});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax and $.post support fail/success etc events that fire when they complete succesfully or with failure, simply call the next ajax then.. like so:

```
            $.ajax({
                url: 'someurl',
                type: "POST"
            }).success(function (data, textStatus, jqXhr) {
                // ajax call is done, do another one
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'someurl',
                    type: "POST"
                }).success(function (data2, textStatus2, jqXhr2) {
                    // 2nd ajax call is done
                }).error(function (jqXhr2, testStatus2, errorThrown2) {
                    // ajax call error, alert user!
                });
            }).error(function (jqXhr, testStatus, errorThrown) {
                // ajax call error, alert user!
            });
```